# Upsert trigger on insert that preserves update behaviors

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am attempting to use an insert trigger to aid in some data import scripts.

I want to automatically update a row if it is already found in the database, however I do not wish to lose data in the process

This trigger will perform an upsert

however it will override pre-existing data in some cases.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial primary_key
    foo int null,
    bar int default 9001,
    baz int null
);

CREATE FUNCTION upsert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE users 
        SET name = NEW.name,
            foo = NEW.foo,
            bar = NEW.bar,
            baz = NEW.baz,
            modified_at = NOW()
        WHERE id = NEW.id;

        IF found THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER upsert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE upsert();
```

I want to only add/update data, not revert to defaults or null during the automated data loading process.

```
INSERT INTO users(id, foo, bar, baz) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO users(id, foo) VALUES (1, 10);
```

would result in

```
id: 1, 
foo: 10,
bar: 9001,
baz: null
```

when really i want

```
id: 1, 
foo: 10,
bar: 3,
baz: 4
```

can i do this with pure plpgsql ?

would it make more sense to flip it and make this an update trigger that tries to insert instead?

also, since I'll be inserting/updating massive datasets, performance is key.

Comment: I don't think a trigger can turn an insert into an update, but a rule would be able to: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-update.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe - a `BEFORE INSERT ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger can `RETURN NULL` to skip that row, and if it did an `UPDATE` before returning it could effectively translate an insert into an update. Locking the table would be necessary to make this safe, and it wouldn't be as fast as a bulk upsert using a join, but I think it'd work ok.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you elaborate?  i'm not seeing a way to selectively handle the update with a rule